# Limit the number of form submissions

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Is there a way to limit the number of forms that can be submitted? This would come in handy if I needed to limit the number of entries for a contest, or registration for an event, like there are only 100 tickets.

It's a HTML form with a PHP mailer

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible, but you'd have to program your mailer script to do it.

Comment: Set a session variable with a counter, and make `$counter++` when a form is submitted. Just think a little... There are tons of methods to achieve the same

Comment: how would a session variable help in this case @MarcosPérezGude?! 100 form submits is not a limit per user

Comment: Store a counter in a database/local file maybe? (database is probably better as its easier to lock tables to ensure you don't get two simultaneous submissions).

Comment: @MarioPlantosar where do you read in the post that it's global and not per user? There are a lot of possible behaviours. Don't feed bad questions. Just vote to close.

Comment: Can you give more information? Are you trying to limit how many times the form gets filled out? Or how many entries into a database it makes? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude have you read the question? It says "number of entries for a contest, or registration for an event", I highly doubt it that someone would like to limit number of registrations for an event to 100 per person, instead of 100 people for the entire event.

Comment: @frits i try to limit how many time a checkbox in a form can be selected. And this global and not per user.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table in a database where you'll insert some info about these tickets (or just use the table as a counter). Each form submit inserts something in the table and before each submit you check if number of rows in a table is less than 100, if it's more just prevent submit and tell the user that all of the tickets (or whatever) are gone, better luck next time.

Comment: what's the easyest way to do this?

`<input type = "radio" name="schicht_freitag" id = "barfr18" value = "barfr18" /><label for = "barfr18">18.00-22.00</label>`

That's my Checkbox and it should only be available 5 times

Comment: This is not a trivial task and will require your changing the script on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table that a.i. primary id and then add a column for email and make it unique.  Then if ID > 100 display something else.